# AFNetworking won't allow large file upload

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking-2

With AFNetworking I'm trying to upload an image (1280x990) with size: 33695.  The code below works perfectly with smaller images (ie:390x390) but the larger image throws an error:

```
[client POST:@"/upload_image" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {

    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"image" fileName:@"image.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];

} success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * task, id responderData) {

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * task, NSError * error) {

}];
```

ERROR thrown:

```
NSDebugDescription = "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.";
```

I've searched many other posts and there doesn't seem to be anything referring to issues with a larger image size.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the error raised as the result of the server sending back a non-JSON response? What is the actual response received. Did you use Charles to see what is actually sent / received ?

Comment: The error is not a result of the server sending back a non-JSON response, I used Charles and there wasn't even a server call that went out.  However, with a smaller image (ie: I resize the image to be 320x320) the call goes out and all is wonderful. It would seem that the AFHTTPSessionManager doesn't like the larger file.

Comment: It's a server side issue. Server sending you wrong json please contact to server guy.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the author of AFNetworking, plz use appendPartWithFileURL instead. Because the data will be stream from disk.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issues when I tried using AFNetworking.  I have since switched to using RestKit and SDWebImage to handle the asynchronous loading and caching of images... and it works like a charm.  You may want to take a look at this recent Quora post to better compare the differences between them.... Mainly the one con to Restkit was async and caching, but with little effort SDWebImage takes care of that with one line of code.

http://www.quora.com/iOS-Development/RestKit-vs-AFNetworking-What-are-the-pros-and-cons